# json_encode(string) giving backslashes in response

Tags: php, json

I am creating an array of objects in js and sending it to one of my controllers after stringify'ing the array.

```
   var arr = new Array();

                for(i=0;i<noOfDeals;i++){

                var deals = {'percentageMin':document.getElementById("pmin"+i).value,
                               'percentageMax':document.getElementById("pmax"+i).value,
                                'modelApplicable': document.getElementById("model"+i).value,
                                'maxCashback' : document.getElementById("maxcash"+i).value,
                                'dealId' : document.getElementById("deal"+i).value                              
                };
                arr.push(deals);
                }
                alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

                 $.ajax({method:'get',url:'abc?data='+JSON.stringify(arr),success:function(response) {
                        //response = JSON.parse(response);
                         response = JSON.parse(response);
                        alert(response.body);
                         response = JSON.parse(response.body);
                        if(response.status != undefined && response.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                                alert('Merchant details updated successfully. Refresh the page to see the changes.');
                        }
                        else {
                                alert('Could not update merchant details, Some Error Occurred');
                        }
                }});
```

In my controller i am encoding the data and then sending to hit the API :

```
public function updateselectedmerchants(){
                if (isset($_GET['data'])) {

                        $str_data = $_GET['data'];

                        print_r(json_encode(array('deals' => $str_data)));

                        die;
                }
        }
```

The Output :

```
{"deals":"[{\"percentageMin\":\"1.00\",\"perentageMax\":\"0.00\",\"modelApplicable\":\"3\",\"maxCashback\":\"30.00\",\"dealId\":\"7\"}"}
```

The desired output :

```
{"deals":[{\"percentageMin\":\"1.00\",\"perentageMax\":\"0.00\",\"modelApplicable\":\"3\",\"maxCashback\":\"30.00\",\"dealId\":\"7\"}]}
```

There are three things which are unwanted in the output which is coming :

```
1) The double quotes before the first square brackets should not be there.
2) The ending square bracket is not present
3) "/" appearing
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
$str_data = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);
print_r(json_encode(array('deals' => $str_data)));
```

Otherwise `$str_data` remains a string, and will be JSON encoded as such, while it looks like you want it to be a PHP array structure, and then encode all of that into valid JSON again.

See this [PHP 'fiddle'](http://www.tehplayground.com/#mXuvncgWD)

Answer (score 0):

You probably generate " or ' somewhere you dont want to.

Not sure if it work 100%, but try:

```
public function updateselectedmerchants(){
                if (isset($_GET['data'])) {

                        $str_data = json_decode($_GET['data']);

                        print_r(json_encode(array('deals' => $str_data)));

                        die;
                }
        }
```

You should try PHP approach:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Just decode array and encode it on the other side.

Comment: Hi Rav, Thankyou for the prompt reply. So according to you the issue might with the url encoding : The get parameter i am sending : JSON.stringify(arr).? Also, how can i JSON.parse() in php.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up a bit. I meant json_decode instead of JSON.parse.